# How to save multiples files as .txt from a list of data frames

Tags: r

I want to use a defined function `morph`on an entire folder /folder of .txt files and afterwards save all the new files to another folder /folder2.

How can I use `lapply` to cycle through every file and return another file that can be saved to the new folder? If possible retaining the old name as well!
Currently a list of multiple data.frames is created, none being named.

Code is something I came up with, but doesn't work as intended.

```
old.files <- list.files(path="/Users/F/folder/", pattern="*.txt", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)

new.files <- paste0("/Users/F/folder2/New_Profile_",1:length(old.files),".txt")



morph <- function (x){

tx0  <- read.table(x,row.names = NULL,col.names= c("Time","Stage"), skip=7, stringsAsFactors = F)


tx1<- as.data.frame(ifelse(tx0 == "Wach",0,
             ifelse(tx0=="N1",2,
                    ifelse(tx0=="N2",1,
                           ifelse(tx0=="N3",3,
                                  ifelse(tx0=="N4",4,
                                         ifelse(tx0=="Rem",5,
                                                ifelse(tx0=="Bewegung",0,
                                                       ifelse(tx0=="A",0,
                                                       tx0[tx0==""]<-tx0$Time)))))))))
mutate(tx1, Epoch=1:n())

}

files.list <- as.list(lapply (old.files, morph))
file.copy(from = files.list,to=new.files)
```

Comment: I don't think the `ifelse` works on the data.frame object `tx0`.  Id you meant converting to `matrix`?

Comment: @akrun works perfectly fine, up until the extraction of as files from the list

Comment: It works because you are converting to `matrix`, but it is not a good way

Comment: @MartinGal sorry typo, edited

Comment: @akrun Why not a good way ? what way is better ?

Answer (score 0):

If we need to save the files

```
out <- lapply(old.files, morph)
 lapply(seq_along(out), function(i) write.table(out[[i]], file = new.files[i]))
```